# Google Sheets Column Wrap

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 columns of data but I don't want them to carry on down the page.  I want the columns to fill the page (3 rows of 3 columns) and then carry on to the next page.  Is this possible?  Added image to try and explain it better.

[image: Column Wrap]

Answer (score 0):

> I want the columns to fill the page (3 rows of 3 columns)...

- just put everything you have in **Sheet1** in first 3 columns
- then hit that **+** to add **Sheet2** where you paste this:

  - cell **A1**: **`=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:C3)`**
- hit **+** again to add **Sheet3** where you paste this:

  - cell **A1**: **`=INDEX(Sheet1!A4:C6)`**
- etc...

  - cell **A1**: **`=INDEX(Sheet1!A7:C9)`**

(to automate it you will need to use script)